# How to make a Question/Answer with multiples answer possible

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner making a Questions/Answers in Python, and manage to deal make a simple "Question/Answer" with 1 answer possible, it works well but I wanted to try to have multiples answer possible, for exemple if there is 5 questions, 2 could be good, but the user can only select 1.
Here's my code, it doesn't work at the end the score will always be 0 whatever I choose.

```
class Question:
def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
     self.prompt = prompt
     self.answer = answer

question_prompts = [
    "Press 1 if the moon is blue, press 2 if it's white\n",
    "Press 1 if an apple is purple, press 2 if it's red ",
    "answer 1 and 2\n"
]

reponse = [
    [1, 2],
    [2],
    [1, 2]
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], reponse[0]),
    Question(question_prompts[1], reponse[1]),
    Question(question_prompts[2], reponse[2]),
]

def quiz(questions):
   score = 0
   for question in questions:
     answer = input(question.prompt)
     if answer == question.answer:
        score += 1
print("tu as eu ", score, "/",len(questions))

quiz(questions)
```

I tried to use an array for the answers but I didn't manage to make it work, here's the version working with only 1 answer.

```
class Question:
def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
    self.prompt = prompt
    self.answer = answer

question_prompts = [
    "Press 1 if the moon is blue, press 2 if it's white\n",
    "Press 1 if an apple is purple, press 2 if it's red ",
    "answer 1 and 2\n"
]


questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "1"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "2"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "1"),
]

def quiz(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:

        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
print("tu as eu ", score, "/",len(questions))

quiz(questions)
```

I have no idea what to do, can someone help me please.

Comment: Use `in` instead of `==`: `if int(answer) in question.answer:`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works well now